# Repainting issue with barmerge.lookahead_on in security

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, pine-script-v4

I tried to extract closing data from higher timeframe. But It is repainting when I add the
`lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on`. It is not repainting when the lookahead is not entered. Not sure what's wrong with it.

I tried both `barstate.isrealtime` and `barstate.isconfirmed`. But both repaints.

```
f_secureSecurity(_symbol, _res, _src) => request.security(_symbol, _res, _src[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on) 
Htfclose = f_secureSecurity(syminfo.tickerid, '60', close)
```

and

```
f_secure(_symbol, _res, _src) => request.security(_symbol, _res, _src[barstate.isconfirmed ? 0 : 1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
Htfclose_1 = f_secure(syminfo.tickerid, '60', close)
```

and also this

```
f_security(_symbol, _res, _src, _repaint) => request.security(_symbol, _res, _src[_repaint ? 0 : barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
Htfclose_2 = f_security(syminfo.tickerid, '60', close, false)
```

And I know it will not repaint if I use `_src[1]`.

What would be the possible way to make it non-repaint with `lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on` and `_src[barstate.isconfirmed ? 0 : 1]` or `_src[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at the last closed HTF bar when requesting data from higher timeframes if you don't want any repainting.

You can use `barstate.isconfirmed` would refer to your chart's timeframe so you cannot use that to avoid repainting.

You can use `barstate.isrealtime` but you need an additional check at the end of your function call.

See below:

```
f_security(_symbol, _res, _src, _repaint) => request.security(_symbol, _res, _src[_repaint ? 0 : barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])[_repaint ? 0 : barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]
```

Please note that there are two `barstate.isrealtime` checks in the above code.

More readings:

- [Understanding lookahead](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html#understanding-lookahead)
- [How to avoid repainting when using security()](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/)

Comment: Thanks. This code is not repainting but if I include `lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on` in it, it repaints. I asked is there a way to make it non repainting with lookahead on?